# Drug indication data for only cancer phenotype from Chembl

Tags: cancer, drugs, cheminformatics

I am interested in getting the drug indication data for all drugs in the database using sqlite.

I used following step to get this

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("chembl_30.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM drug_indication", con)
```

With this I am getting a table with columns efo_id and efo_term for all disease.

```
drugind_id  record_id   molregno    max_phase_for_ind   mesh_id mesh_heading    efo_id  efo_term
0   22606   1390869 675774  2   D045743 Scleroderma, Diffuse    EFO:0000404 diffuse scleroderma
1   22607   1390869 675774  4   D001172 Arthritis, Rheumatoid   EFO:0000685 rheumatoid arthritis
2   22608   1390869 675774  2   D008180 Lupus Erythematosus, Systemic   EFO:0002690 systemic lupus erythematosus
3   22609   1343491 675576  3   D009203 Myocardial Infarction   EFO:0000612 myocardial infarction
4   22610   1344515 438435  4   D011471 Prostatic Neoplasms EFO:0001663 prostate carcinoma
```

Is there any way I can I filter EFO's based on cancer, so that I get drug indication data (max_phase) for all chembl ids used in cancer?

`some important links`

https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/db_schema

https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/compound_report_card/CHEMBL941/

Thank you